# `texdoc` gives warnings

Tags: texlive, texdoc

First of all, English is not my native language, but Chinese is.

I installed TL2020 yesterday. I chose the option `install for all users` and `portable` (I can't remember the options' name, sorry). Now there are TL2019 at `d:\texlive\2019` and TL2020 at `d:\texlive\2020` installed on my pc together. However when I use `texdoc` to open a doc, it opens the doc but gives warnings

```latex
texdoc ctex
texdoc warning: Failed to create cache file in D:/texlive/2020/texmf-var/texdoc/cache-tlpdb.lua:
texdoc warning: Permission denied
```

When I change the path to `d:\texlive\2019\bin\win32` and use `texdoc`, it works without warnings. By the way, my TL2019 was installed with the default options, not for all users, also not portable.

Please tell me if anyone knows what leads to these warnings and how to fix them. Thanks a lot.

Comment: oh, I tested again `texdoc` in TL2020, it couldn't open a doc, but only gave warnings.

Comment: Change
`D:/texlive/2020/texmf-var` and all subdirs
to be writable for you
by
`explorer -> property -> security`
as an administrator.

Comment: @AkiraKakuto Thanks, it works after  changing it